# Will a dog live longer if it eats dry dog food all the time?

Tags: dogs, health, diet, feeding

I'm not talking about canned dog food. I'm talking about kibble or dry dog food.

I've had dogs for 22+ years and don't give them dry dog food, or any kind of dog food for that matter, because its quality is ridiculously low and they don't enjoy it. And the results? Let's just say my dogs have a habit of living past their "sell by date," usually by an extra 5 - 7 years.

A friend of mine has gotten her second family dog, a golden retriever, and she spends a silly amount on a specific dog food that the dog has been on since birth. She's one year old now and still eating the same dog food.

I don't think she enjoys it too much as she's eating her own feces like it's her last meal.

Would she live longer eating dog food or real food?

Comment: This is more of a rant than a question. Yes, millions of dogs live long and full lives on kibble alone.

Comment: the same exact brand and flavour? there entire life, think id loose my mind if I had the same box of cornflakes for 100 years wouldn't you?

Comment: yes, the same brand and flavor. Dogs don't need variety as much as people do. In fact, radical changes in a dog's diet often cause digestive distress, which is why it is best to changes brands gradually by mixing the two for a while

Comment: @jalynn2 it's just she tends not to eat her dry food at all some days and then eats it the next. It's just me ha can't not wonder if the dog is happy eating it day in day out :/

Comment: Wow wiki only has 10 dogs recorded at 22+ years.  Are you dogs on this list?   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_oldest_dogs

Comment: No but we had golden retrievers, Shih Tzu, beagles and they left we'll past there estimate life estimate

Comment: Related [Specific Dry dog food brand question](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2134)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Yes, they will

The pet food business is big business.  Companies won't last too long if they produce food that's unsuitable for their target market.  An awful lot of science goes into the ingredients for pet food (wet and dry) to ensure that it meets the dietary requirements of the animals.

People choose dry food (kibble) for a variety of reasons:

- It keeps well
- It doesn't smell
- It doesn't make a mess if it gets spilt
- It's easily transportable
- It's easy to weigh out portions
- Dogs like eating it
- Less waste (there's no tins and because it keeps better, you can buy it in larger bags)

Yes, it's probably more expensive, but to many owners, the convenience outweighs the downsides of buying wet food.

As to whether dogs live longer on wet or dry food - that's pretty much impossible to prove one way or the other, considering just how many factors there are in a dogs life.  I've also seem plenty of old dogs do perfectly well on dry food.

Comment: There's another reason dry food is better.  According to my vet, dental disease is probably the greatest cause of dogs' early deaths.  He said cleaning their teeth lengthens their life span by an average of 2 years.  I haven't been able to find documentation backing this up, but I know my in-laws' dogs (who were always fed canned food or soft food) ended up losing all their teeth long before their deaths.  In the absence of regular teeth brushing, dry food helps keep their teeth clean.